# How hard/expensive is it to set up and maintain a Dojo alone?

Tags: warframe

I've been playing long enough to get most weapons that don't require research. Since I don't have anyone to play with and don't want to go out searching for a clan, I guess I'm going to have to do this alone.

How expensive (credits/forma/platinum/other resources) is it going to be to start a clan and build enough Dojo facilities to start researching new stuff? Are there any maintenance costs or tasks that I need to be aware of after the Dojo is built?